# How do I call a number with Twilio Studio flow REST API execution

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The purpose is simply to call a number (my number) and have a message start playing. 
I have created a Studio Flow like so:
[image]

And published that flow. 
I've also bought a phone number and it is activated for voice & messaging. I can receive a test voice call with code and using TwiML).

In the settings of my phone number I have the following:

> Accept: Voice Calls
>
> Configure with: .. Studio ..
>
> A call comes in: Studio Flow (and selected the correct flow)

I then proceed to use Postman to try and trigger my Flow using a POST request with the following parameters:
[image: postman settings]

And the following body parameters where the To number is my number which is verified in my trial account, and the from is the number i purchased in twilio:
[image: postman settings v2]

After clicking on Send in postman I receive a 200 OK message, but I am not receiving a call on my phone. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The variable you are using as the number to dial out from Studio is `{{contact.channel.address}}` but the `contact` variable refers to ["data about the current contact engaging with your flow, such as their phone number"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#context-variables).

Since you have triggered the flow with a REST API call there is not a contact that is currently engaging with the flow, so this won't give you the number you want.

You are, however, sending in some parameters from your HTTP request from Postman, notably a `To` parameter. Your data that you send to the flow endpoint like this will be available under the `trigger` context variable.

So, you should update your widget to use `{{trigger.To}}` instead (and you probably don't need `From`, as that is the number associated with the flow, or `Body`).

Let me know how you get on with that.

Comment: Fantastic, hope the rest of your app goes well.